# Which HTML5 mobile framework do you recommend?

Tags: html, mobile, extjs, jqmobi

jqMobi? Sencha? Or other one? Why?

Thank you!

I have to repeat contents above in order to being able to post this question.

jqMobi? Sencha? Or other one? Why?

Thank you!

Comment: You may have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks there is a mobile section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the lead dev of jqMobi.  bensnider is correct, in that Sencha is an all in one type of framework. But a lot of people have had problems with that.  You can't use a single component in your project, it's "Sencha" or nothing.  If you like that, it's a solid framework.

With jqUi, the UI part of jqMobi, you can use backbone.js as the back end or another MVC type framework and use jqUi as just the presentation layer.

It also depends on what your target is.  If you are soley iOS, Sencha shines there, but Android support on Sencha (even V2) is still really lacking.

Answer (score 2):

Sencha Touch 2 has been really nice for us (barring the pre-release churn) since it bridges UI and data all in one framework. V2 has also added some really nice MVC support with routes and and actual controllers and all that jazz. As always its data stores and models are very nice, now borrowing heavily from Ext. Now that the beta has landed I highly recommend starting new projects with it.

Looking at the other frameworks, most of them aren't an all in one type framework, requiring you to depend on or create libraries for data storage, remote resources, etc. In addition, Sencha is now probably the most mature framework, and has a nice developer community around it.

Answer (score 0):

Another key consideration is which specific devices/platforms you want to support, and what the experience on those devices is.  e.g. Sencha Touch 2 does not support Android 3.  I'd encourage you to try the example applications on some physical devices you want to support:

http://www.jqmobi.com/testdrive/

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/

For disclosure, I've developed a business app using Sencha Touch but not jqMobi.

Answer (score -2):

It really depends on what you are trying to do, what your comfort zone is etc.